# Why is TypeScript adding .default to a globally defined import?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

I have an external library `thing.d.ts` file with a global definition inside:

```
declare var thing: ThingStatic;
export default thing;
```

I reference npm module in my TypeScript:

```
import thing from 'thing';
...
thing.functionOnThing();
```

When I transpile the TS (targeting ES6) it looks something like this:

```
const thing_1 = require("thing");
...
thing_1.default.functionOnThing();
```

This then throws an error:

> Cannot read property 'functionOnThing' of undefined

Why is TypeScript adding `.default` between `thing_1` and `functionOnThing()`?

There is no property named `default` on `ThingStatic`, and no `default` property on the underlying JS object that the `.d.ts` file defines.

Why is TypeScript adding the property and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with global TS definitions and `"module": "commonjs"` in the `tsconfig.json`.

You can either use global TS definitions and stitch all your output into a single file, or you can use modules and directly import them.

The error here is due to the `require` returning the module context, and the name of the `default` being irrelevant - it always becomes `default`...

```
declare var thing: ThingStatic;
export thing; // Explicit export for thing
export default thing; // Default export for thing
```

Now `require` will return this context, so with `commonjs` modules:

```
import module from 'thing';
var thing = module.default; // From the default export
var alsoThing = module.thing; // From the named export
```

However, I've found this to be inconsistent, so switched to es6 modules:

```
import thing from './thing'; // Import default
import { thing } from './thing'; // Import named
const thing = (await import('path/to/thing.js')).default; // Import dynamic
```

Answer (score 24):

```
import thing from 'thing';
```

This line of code *means* "import the `default` export from the module `'thing'` and bind it to the local name `thing`".

TypeScript does as you requested and accesses the `default` property of the module object.

What you probably meant to write was

```
import * as thing from 'thing';
```

Comment: Ok, now I have `thing.default` in my TypeScript so at least I can work around it. Is this a bug in the library I'm using? How should the `.d.ts` be written so that the global variable can be imported?

Comment: The .d.ts file should say `export = thing` instead of `export default thing`

Comment: I've just tried that, it gives me an error: `TS2309 An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.`

Comment: The other, less likely possibility is there is indeed a default export that `thing` module is supposed to have, but it's not handled properly by the module loader or runtime that you are using.

Comment: OK, I've tried asking that in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150148