# How should I define a global TypeScript variable in a definition file so that it can be imported?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an external JS library with a global parameter:

```
function Thing() {  ...  }
...
var thing = new Thing();
```

There is a TypeScript definition file, so in `thing.d.ts`:

```
declare var thing: ThingStatic;
export default thing;

export interface ThingStatic {
    functionOnThing(): ThingFoo;
}

export interface ThingFoo {
    ... and so on
```

Then I import this into my own TS files with:

```
import thing from 'thing';
import {ThingFoo} from 'thing';
...
const x:ThingFoo = thing.functionOnThing();
```

The problem is that transpiles to:

```
const thing_1 = require("thing");
...
thing_1.default.functionOnThing();
```

Which throws an error. I've asked about that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148057), and the suggestion is to use:

```
import * as thing from 'thing';
```

That doesn't fix it - it gives me `thing.default` in TS but then that's undefined once transpiled to JS.

I think there's something wrong with `thing.d.ts` - there must be a way to define a typed global parameter that can be imported.

How should I write `thing.d.ts` so that it represents the JS correctly and doesn't transpile to include `default` or other properties not actually present?

Comment: try declaring with a string name - '''declare var 'thing'.   I don't really understand _why_ this works but I had to do the same thing in a slightly different scenario.  (in my case I switched from declare module foo to declare module 'foo')

Answer (score 0):

If the only way to use that library is by accessing its globals (as opposed to importing it as node module or amd or umd module), then the easiest way to go is have a declaration file without any `export`s at top level. Just declaring a variable is enough. To use it, you have to include that declaration file when compiling your typescript code, either by adding it to `files` or `include`  in `tsconfig.json`, or directly on command line. You also have to include the library with a `<script>` tag at runtime.

Example: **thing.d.ts**

```
declare var thing: ThingStatic;

declare interface ThingStatic {
    functionOnThing(): ThingFoo;
}

declare interface ThingFoo {
}
```

**test-thing.ts**

```
const x:ThingFoo = thing.functionOnThing();
```

can be compiled together

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc test-thing.ts thing.d.ts
```

the result in `test-thing.js`:

```
var x = thing.functionOnThing();
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953848/what-are-ambient-typings-in-the-typescript-typings-tool) about ambient declarations.

Note: there are module loaders out there that allow using global libraries as if they were modules, so it's possible to use `import` statement instead of `<script>` tag, but how to configure these module loaders to do that is another, more complicated question.

Comment: That doesn't work. Without the `export` statement in `thing.d.ts` then `test-thing.ts` just doesn't know what the global variable `thing` is. Ambient declarations work but defeat the entire point of having `thing.d.ts` in the first place as now everything is just `any`. This global variable is the entry point to a large API - I want the definition to be visible to TypeScript.

Comment: No everything is typed and not `any` - why are you saying that "everything is just any"?. And if it's really a global variable there is no way to import it - you can't import thing which is not exported by modular javascript code. Declaration file just describes the reality as it's defined in javascript library, it can't change it.

Comment: That's what I get when I try to use this. I'm beginning to think that may be a bug in Visual Studio though. I'll do some testing with alternate implementations.