# Why does typescript allow me to import dependencies it can't use at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

You can see my sample project here: https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/typescript-stub-examples/tree/JavaScript-import-invalid

I have created this file called main.ts:

```js
import uuid from "uuid";

console.log(uuid.v4());
```

Although typescript is fine with this import, when I try to `node main.js`, it gives this error:

```
console.log(uuid_1["default"].v4());
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'v4' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\root\lib\main.js:5:31)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

If I change the file to this, it executes fine:

```js
import * as uuid from "uuid";

console.log(uuid.v4());
```

If the first version is invalid, why doesn't typescript inform me?

I have a multi file tsconfig setup. Check the github project for more details, but here are the shared compiler options which may be relevant:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "composite": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
    },
}
```

Here is how the main.js looks:

#### doesn't work

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");
var uuid_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("uuid"));
console.log(uuid_1["default"].v4());
```

#### works

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var tslib_1 = require("tslib");
var uuid = tslib_1.__importStar(require("uuid"));
console.log(uuid.v4());
```

Comment: Can you edit to show the whole tsc emit?

Comment: I would recommend against `esModuleInterop`, it can cause strange issues. One reason your error might happen is if the types of the package you use are wrong.

Comment: @sno2 not sure what that means. You talking about what tsc outputs to stdout, or the files it generates?

Comment: @Evert really? Says it's recommended here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan I mean including the entire file that it generated in `main.js`

Comment: @sno2 updated. hth

Comment: What version of `uuid` do you have installed? Do you also happen to have `@types/uuid` installed? If so, what version?

Comment: FYI you're using `uuid` incorrectly; there is no default export. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/562#issuecomment-789297737

Comment: @Phil I have the types installed and I'm aware I am using it incorrectly. I have this other project, and strangely, it doesn't seem to care if I'm using it incorrectly. I can execute the same main without error. I've spent an hour trying to figure out the difference between the two, copying TS config properties from one to the other, but I can't get this github project to act the same way.

Comment: @Phil    "uuid": "^8.3.0" and     "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",

Comment: The issue with esModuleInterop is that it can actually create incompatibilities. This is especially true if you create libraries for others to consume.

Comment: This seems quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148057/why-is-typescript-adding-default-to-a-globally-defined-import potentially even, identical, with an answer that clearly explains why this occurs and how to remedy it

Comment: @KevinB I doubt it: some of the properties we're talking about here didn't even exist at the time of those answers. Regardless, neither of them are an explanation to why typescript doesn't report an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I kind of feel guilty answering my own bounty question, so I'm going to mark it as community. The reason I'm writing my own is because I feel like the other answer really buries the lede. I had to perform hours and hours of my own research *after* reading it to be able to write this. That being the case, I think my answer will be more helpful to people that start in my boat, where I didn't know what I didn't know. I also think there's an additional solution to the problem, though it would be more invasive.

My original question was, "If the first version is invalid, why doesn't typescript inform me?" Here is the other answer's explanation:

> Because you have enabled esModuleInterop which also enables allowSyntheticDefaultImports. The CommonJS bundle is actually incompatible with that option but TypeScript doesn't know.

This is absolutely true, but when it comes to understanding what's going on, it's the tip of the iceberg:

If you look at the reference documentation, it *recommends* you set [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) to true. Why would it make that recommendation if it reduces type safety? Well, that is not why it recommends you set it to true. In fact, this setting *does not* reduce type safety -- it increases it by fixing some legacy typescript bugs, specifically two that deal with how typescript handles `requires`. You can read the documentation for more details on that, but in my opinion, if you are using node libraries, I think it's a good idea to set esModuleInterop to true.

But! esModuleInterop has a side effect. At the very bottom of its documentation, it says:

> Enabling esModuleInterop will also enable [allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports).

Err... kinda. IMO, this documentation is incorrect. What it should really say is, "Enabling esModuleInterop will **default** [allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) to true." If you look at the allowSyntheticDefaultImports documentation, it says this on the right-hand side:

[image]

Hey, notice how in that upper right-hand corner it doesn't say this setting is recommended? That's probably because this setting reduces type safety: it allows you to type `import React from "react";` instead of `import * as React from "react";` when the module does not explicitly specify a default export.

Normally (i.e. with allowSyntheticDefaultImports set to false), this would be an error... because it is: you shouldn't be able to default import a module unless it has a default export. Setting this to true makes the compiler say, "Nah, this is fine."

But, when you set allowSyntheticDefaultImports to true, "this flag does not affect the JavaScript emitted by TypeScript." What this means is, this flag lets you pretend the library was written one way at compile time even though it wasn't. At runtime, this will error. Why does the setting even exist? I have no idea, but it probably has to do with historical reasons:

> This option brings the behavior of TypeScript in-line with Babel, where extra code is emitted to make using a default export of a module more ergonomic.

It seems like there was(/is?) a point in time where everybody was just assumed to be using Babel. I am not doing that, so the "ergonomic" benefit becomes a runtime error.

> As a cleaner method, you should import uuid with import { v4 } from 'uuid';

True, but I think it would also be a good idea to explicitly set allowSyntheticDefaultImports to false. It gives you more type safety. Not only that, it makes `import uuid from "uuid";` a compile time error (which it should be).

There is one more thing I don't understand:

Setting allowSyntheticDefaultImports to false also makes imports like `import os from "os";` and `import _ from "lodash";` compile time errors. But those always ran fine when allowSyntheticDefaultImports was true. There must be some piece I'm missing that explains why those work but `uuid` doesn't.

I can't find the source of `os` in my node_modules, but I can look at `lodash`, and its `index.js` does this:

```
module.exports = require('./lodash');
```

In that required file, it says this at the bottom:

```
...
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  // Export lodash.
  var _ = runInContext();

  // Some AMD build optimizers, like r.js, check for condition patterns like:
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object' && define.amd) {
    // Expose Lodash on the global object to prevent errors when Lodash is
    // loaded by a script tag in the presence of an AMD loader.
    // See http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch for more details.
    // Use `_.noConflict` to remove Lodash from the global object.
    root._ = _;

    // Define as an anonymous module so, through path mapping, it can be
    // referenced as the "underscore" module.
    define(function() {
      return _;
    });
  }
  // Check for `exports` after `define` in case a build optimizer adds it.
  else if (freeModule) {
    // Export for Node.js.
    (freeModule.exports = _)._ = _;
    // Export for CommonJS support.
    freeExports._ = _;
  }
  else {
    // Export to the global object.
    root._ = _;
  }
```

I don't really understand what all of this is doing, but I think this is defining a global variable named `_` at runtime? I guess that means, from a typescript perspective, this coincidentally works out. The type declaration files don't have a default, which would normally cause a runtime error, but almost coincidentally, it all works out in the end because the lodash javascript defines a global `_`? *shrug* Maybe this is a pattern that `os` uses, too, but I've already spent enough hours researching this, so I will leave that for another day/question.

Answer (score 7):

Your issue is related to interoperability between TypeScript/ECMAScript modules and CommonJS.

When it comes to the differences between [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules) and [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules:

- [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules are meant to be imported like `const library = require('library')` which allows to retrieve the full `exports` object of that library. There is no notion of default import in [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules)
- [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules) have explicit `export` clauses for every exported item. They also feature a [default import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports) which allows to retrieve the `default` export in a local variable.

In order to implement interoperability between [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules and TypeScript's [default import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports), [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules can have a `default` property.

That `default` property can even be added automatically by TypeScript when [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) is enabled (which also enables [`allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports)). This option adds this helper function at transpilation time:

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
```

Basically what this function does is: if the imported module has the `__esModule` flag set to true, export it as is because the module is intended to be used as an [ECMAScript module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules): `import { feature } from 'library'`. Otherwise, export it inside a wrapper object with a `default` property, which enables the `import localName from 'library'` syntax.

The [`uuid`](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) package is being built with [`@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs) which includes the `__esModule` flag and prevents you from using the [default import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports). Other packages like [`lodash`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) don't include this flag, which allows TypeScript to add the `default` property.

As a conclusion, TypeScript provides options to interoperate with legacy [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules but these options don't work with "ECMAScript aware" [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) modules. TypeScript cannot warn or error out at transpilation time because a [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) module interface has no representation other than the `exports` object, which is only known at runtime.

Comment: 1. The paragraph above your quote says, "...with esModuleInterop **false or not set** ... there are two parts in particular which turned out to be flawed assumptions:" I'm paraphrasing, so let me know if I left out some crucial information. My interpretation is the code *doesn't* work that way with esModuleInterop set to true.

Comment: 2. Since `uuid` is using commonjs and typescript is esm (I think?), doesn't it mean I need to be able to "interoperate" between the two? I thought that's what this key is for.

Comment: You're right the module resolution is actually unrelated to `esModuleInterop` I've corrected this

Comment: "the `import * as uuid from "uuid";` line works because it's equivalent to `const uuid = require('uuid');`" Where are you getting this information?

Comment: It's just one way to grasp it. The official definition is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports) *Import the entire module into a single variable, and use it to access the module exports*. I've edited the conclusion as I eventually found the actual reason why TypeScript allows the default import syntax in your case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm working under the ESM module environment.

I have been struggling with the `uuid` package import issue multiple times, in the past years.

Today I ran into it again, and found something new to me and like to share it under your great analytics answer.

TL;DR: the behavior of the `import UUID from 'uuid'` is different when the `uuid` package is dependent directly, or indirectly.

> I think this is related to the ESM behavior.

| package.json dependency with `uuid` | `import * as UUID from 'uuid'` | `import UUID from 'uuid'` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| directly (tsc) | OK | OK |
| directly (runtime) | OK | `SyntaxError: The requested module 'uuid' does not provide an export named 'default'` |
| in-directly (tsc) | OK | `Module "node_modules/@types/uuid/index" has no default export.ts(1192)` |
| in-directly (runtime) | `TypeError: UUID.v4 is not a function` | OK |

1. "directly dependency with `uuid`" means we have a `uuid` in the `dependencies` of package.json
2. "indirectly dependency with `uuid`" means we have no `uuid` in the `dependencies` of package.json (but other dependency module has included it)

### Conclusion

It seems that there is only one situation in which the typing system and the runtime both work as expected with ESM: use a direct dependency to the `uuid` package.

Always `npm install --save uuid`. (see my [issue here](https://github.com/Chatie/tsconfig/issues/43) with commits)