# `import XXX from` returns undefined while `const XXX = require` works in ts-node + Gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, ts-node

Works (file is `gulpfile.ts`):

```
const Gulp = require("gulp");
```

Does not work (no TypeScript errors but `Gulp` is `undefined`):

```
import Gulp from "gulp";
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {}
  }
}
```

Command:

```
gulp <Any declared Gulp task>
```

Comment: How `gulpfile.ts` looks like? Unexpected behaviour may be caused by incorrect export logic

Comment: @Leemellaret, thank you for the comment. Just `import Gulp from "gulp"; console.log(Gulp);` is enough for the minimal reproduction. Of cource Gulp will tell `Task never defined: Deploy`, but `undefined` will be output before that. The `undefined` will disappear if replace the first line to `var Gulp = require("gulp");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `import Gulp from "gulp"` you are trying to import the `default` export of `gulp` which seems not to exist.

The actual equivalent of `const Gulp = require("gulp");` in TypeScript is the "import all of the exports into a single variable" syntax:

```
import * as Gulp from 'gulp';
```

If you need the `import Gulp from "gulp"` syntax, you can add the `default` import automatically with the [`esModuleInterop` TypeScript option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop)

More information about CommonJS interoperability and the [`esModuleInterop` TypeScript option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) in my other answer here: [Why does typescript allow me to import dependencies it can't use at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69200697/why-does-typescript-allow-me-to-import-dependencies-it-cant-use-at-runtime#answer-69272730)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You solution is working, but I know that `import Gulp from "gulp";`  working too under certain conditions. "I know" means I have some working projects with `import Gulp from "gulp";`. But what it this condition?

Comment: Found this condition! It was missing `"esModuleInterop": true`. May I ask you to add this in your great answer?

Comment: Yes sure I'll do it later today (on my mobile right now)

Comment: I'll accept your answer once you will update it. Thanks again!

Comment: I've edited my answer, thanks in advance for the acceptance!

Comment: As I promised ~_^